# Query on random number generation in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, random

I've been having a problem recently with Actionscript 3.0 and random number generation for this basic game I'm developing. I'm new to random numbers and math in AS3 so please forgive me if I come across a bit stupid. So, in this game I have a couple of squares set up, each one called random and then a number between 1-6 after (e.g random1, random2, etc.) So, when a certain obstacle hits a certain object I want this certain obstacle to go to the y of a randomly selected square. So, here's what I have down:

```
spike1.y = random+Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
```

// So like the spike's y is equal to random plus a number between 0-7, so like random+1 or 2 or 3, etc.

I don't if I'm close to fixing it or far. Help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How is it you've called each sqare "random"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this all in the object/class try this:

```
spike1.y = this[ "random"+Math.floor( Math.random()*7 ) ].y;
```

That should have the effect you are looking for.